# Core NSManagedObjectID always return object 0 in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I want to fetch primary key value in core data in Iphone, so I am using NSManagedObjectID to get objectID(Mostly same as PK value ) but I am having problem that It return 0 always

Here is my code block

```
-(NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
{

Maintness_Item *MainItem1; // my object model 
NSManagedObjectID *yourManagedObjectID = [ MainItem1 objectID];
int yourManagedObject_PK = [[[[[yourManagedObjectID URIRepresentation] absoluteString]    lastPathComponent] substringFromIndex:1] intValue];
NSLog(@"This is my managed object ID ...................%d",yourManagedObject_PK);

return 0;
}
```

Note: Here I am returning 0 ,Is it may problem? If any then what should I write here?

Please guide me

Comment: what print in Console ?

Comment: this is my console output --  This is my managed object ID ...................0

Comment: You should log all intermediary steps: URIRepresenation, absoluteString, lastPathComponent, substringFromIndex, and intValue.

Comment: Have you assigned anything to `MainItem1` ? Otherwise it is `nil` and `yourManagedObject_PK` will be zero.

Comment: @MartinR but what should I assign here?

Comment: @kirtiavaiya: What are you actually trying to do? There is already a existingObjectWithID method in the NSManagedObjectContext class. What should your function do? - Your function has a objectID parameter that is not used. Then you call `[ MainItem1 objectID]` but `MainItem` is not defined. - Questions over questions ... :-)

Comment: @MartinR I want to get primary key of particular record

Comment: @kirtiavaiya: If I understand your code correctly, you should replace `int yourManagedObject_PK = [[[[[yourManagedObjectID URIRepresentation] ...` by `int yourManagedObject_PK = [[[[[objectID URIRepresentation] ...`. - But I agree with Mundi's comments that this private key is not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should not use the object id as the private key. It is not an integer and has its own representation. `NSManagedObjectID` is really there for persisting a reference to a particular entity in e.g. user defaults, or to create weak references ("joins") across persistent stores.

There is a URL representation you can use:

```
NSURL *uri = [[myObject objectID] URIRepresentation];
```

You can turn that into `NSData` if you want to keep it, but you could also just serialize the URI.

If you need classic private keys e.g. to communicate with another instance of your data on a server, you should create your own as attributes of your entities. Just don't abuse them to substitute managed object model relationships.

NB: please `UpperCaseNames` only for classes, for instances you should use `lowerCaseName`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSManagedObjectID` doesn't work like that, and neither does `NSString`.

If the managed object hasn't been saved yet, the object ID's absolute string will be something like:

```
x-coredata:///Entity/tE7D63E10-8BE4-41CE-A6DC-C131F6990F062
```

If it *has* been saved, it will be something like

```
x-coredata://F869550C-914E-4160-B8A7-9DD9A82F2CE2/Entity/p2
```

Neither version presents any good targets for `-[NSString intValue]`. You might extract the integer at the end, but *this is not in any way useful, not even a little bit*. You can't use that integer value for anything, anywhere.